# Chaining deferred callbacks

Tags: python, twisted, deferred, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I am trying to chain deferreds in AMP client like following:

Client:

```
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol
from twisted.protocols.amp import AMP

import commands

def connect_protocol(host, port):
    destination = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port)
    d = connectProtocol(destination, AMP())

    def connect(protocol):
        print 'Connecting to server as Mr Spaceman...'
        return protocol.callRemote(commands.Connect,
                                   username='Mr Foo')

    def say(protocol):
        print 'Saying "Hello world" to the server...'
        return protocol.callRemote(commands.Say,
                                   phrase='Hello world')

    d.addCallback(connect)
    d.addCallback(say)


def main(host, port):
    connect_protocol(host, port)
    print 'Connected to %s:%d...' % (host, port)
    reactor.run()

main('127.0.0.1', 12345)
```

Server:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.amp import AMP

import commands

class CommandProtocol(AMP):

    def connect(self, username):
        print "Received connect command: %s." % (username)
        return {}
    commands.Connect.responder(connect)

    def say(self, phrase):
        print "Received phrase \"%s\"." % phrase
        return {}
    commands.Say.responder(say)

def main(port):
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = CommandProtocol
    reactor.listenTCP(port, factory)
    print 'Started AMP server on port %d...' % port
    reactor.run()

main(12345)
```

Only `connect()` is being fired on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enable logging:

```
from sys import stdout
from twisted.python.log import startLogging
startLogging(stdout)
```

Now you'll see what's going on in the program.

Second, at least have a final errback that logs unhandled failures on a `Deferred` so these will show up deterministically rather than depending on the garbage collector:

```
from twisted.python.log import err

...

    d.addCallback(connect)
    d.addCallback(say)
    d.addErrback(err, "connect_protocol encountered some problem")
```

Finally, the result of a Deferred is changed by callbacks and errbacks attached to it.  In this case, the argument passed to `say` is the result of the `Deferred` returned by `connect`.  This will not be the same as the argument to `connect`, so it's not likely you can use `callRemote` on it.

You can fix this in many different ways.  One way that involves minimal code changes (but isn't necessarily the best solution) is to pass the protocol as an extra value in the result of the `connect` `Deferred`:

```
def connect(protocol):
    print 'Connecting to server as Mr Spaceman...'
    d = protocol.callRemote(commands.Connect, username='Mr Foo')
    d.addCallback(lambda result: (protocol, result))
    return d

def say((protocol, result)):
    print 'Saying "Hello world" to the server...'
    return protocol.callRemote(commands.Say,
                               phrase='Hello world')
```

Comment: `d.addCallback(say)` performs `callRemote` operation on a dict, but how do I make 2 unrelated calls from the same client to the same server (`connect` and `say`)?